# How to output file as UTF8 with Signature in C#

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to output an excel file as attachment in ASP.NET and it's hard to encode it in Turkish. Following codes are what I did; I'm leaving the lines that I tried as comments:

```
  var collection = Data.Get<Students>()
    .Where(t => t.Year == activeYear)
    .OrderBy(t => t.Name);

  var total = collection.Count();

  DataTable dt = collection.ToDataTable();
  dt.Columns.Remove("Id");

  string htmlCode = "<table>";

  //add header row
  htmlCode += "<tr>";
  htmlCode += "<td>#</td>";

  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
      htmlCode += "<td>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</td>";
  }

  htmlCode += "</tr>";

  //add rows
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    htmlCode += "<tr>";
    htmlCode += "<td>" + (dt.Rows.Count-i+1).ToString() + "</td>";

    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        htmlCode += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
    }

    htmlCode += "</tr>";
  }

  htmlCode += "</table>";   


  ////////////////////////////////////
  // Encoding part begins here
  ////////////////////////////////////

  var output = htmlCode;

  Encoding encoding =  new UTF8Encoding(true); //Encoding.UTF8; //new UTF8Encoding(true);
  var utf8bytes = encoding.GetBytes(output);
  utf8bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(utf8bytes).ToArray();
  byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(output);
  //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(utf8bytes);
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

  Response.Clear();
  Response.Buffer = true;
  Response.ClearContent();

  string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + Utils.Security.RemoveDiacritics(currentLesson + "-" + activeYear) + ".xls";
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
  //Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

  Response.ContentEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(true); //Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254"); // Encoding.UTF8;
  Response.Output.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
  Response.Flush();
  Response.End();
```

If I use new UTF8Encoding(true) or false, the output is always UTF8 with NO SIGNATURE. If I open the file in Notepad2 and encode it as UTF8 with Signature the names will be displayed correctly.

This is the downloaded Excel file and name appears incorrect in Excel:

[image: img]

This is the modified Excel file in Notepad2 and name appears correct in Excel:

[image]

To correct the names I open downloaded xls file with Notepad2 and change encoding from UTF8 to UTF8 with Signature. Now, how can I do that at server side?

**Update:** The difference between files are shown below in HEX editor screenshot, just 3 bytes added at the beginning of xls flat text file:

[image]

Comment: Here is utf-8 with BOM and the default File.WriteAllText can write with bom to text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the byte list with utf-8 with bom that you should wirte the three byte the head.

You can write the three byte `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF` to your byte list head to make the byte list as the utf-8 with bom encoding

Please see [Byte order mark - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)